# Error during connection to wcf service by ssl

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl

I've done a wcf service, that is published (I can connect to it by browser and I can see the wsdl) but when I try to consume it by a client program that I've written, I obtain an "An error occurred when verifying security for the message" message.

Some detail: consumer and server are on the same machine (so this isn't the case of out-of-sync time between consumer and server), I use a self signed certificate, the service is put in a subsection of a greater solution, and it has a dedicated web.config that overrides the solution one.

Web.config files are the same both on the service side than on consumer side (I've simply done a copy and paste from service to consumer file). Consumer uses basicHttpBinding and TransportWithMessageCredential connection and, after several attempts, even if I've created a service reference to the service by Visual Studio tool, in the consumer code I specify again both the binding type than the endpoint address.

As I've already said, the service uses a self signed certificate, and I've implemented a validation class to validate a non trusted certificate.

When I create the proxy object in my consumer class I don't get any error, I receive it only when I try to consume any method on my service. I've set up the tracelog, but it doesn't seem to show any error, for what I can understand:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>262165</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-10-30T10:41:32.4017455Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{43c6480e-e3fe-4916-b3a3-efaa10881db5}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="7004" ThreadID="6" />
    <Channel />
    <Computer>WKR1007R</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
        <DataItem>
            <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
            <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-IT/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannelReplyReceived.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
            <Description>Ricevuta risposta tramite il canale di richiesta</Description>
            <AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/PBEWS_Client_Test-1-130591392918713557</AppDomain>
            <Source>System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage/2733477</Source>
            <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTraceRecord">
                <MessageProperties>
                    <Encoder>text/xml; charset=utf-8</Encoder>
                    <AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching>
                    <Security>
                        <IsAnonymous>False</IsAnonymous>
                        <WindowsIdentityUsed>False</WindowsIdentityUsed>
                    </Security>
                </MessageProperties>
                <MessageHeaders></MessageHeaders>
            </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
    </DataItem>
</TraceData>
```

Only using Fiddler I can find an error:

> ## Errore server nell'applicazione '/PBEWS_Client_Test'.
>
> ### *Errore durante la verifica della sicurezza del messaggio.*
>
> **Descrizione:** Eccezione non gestita durante l'esecuzione della richiesta Web corrente. Per ulteriori informazioni sull'errore e sul suo punto di origine nel codice, vedere la traccia dello stack.

```
        <b> Dettagli eccezione: </b>System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Errore durante la verifica della sicurezza del messaggio.<br><br>

        <b>Errore nel codice sorgente:</b> <br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <code><pre>
```

Riga 584:
Riga 585:        public R...Contracts.PolPolizza RecuperaPolizza(int idPolizza, bool modalita) {
Riga 586:            return base.Channel.RecuperaPolizza(idPolizza, modalita);
Riga 587:        }
Riga 588:

```
              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

        <b> File di origine: </b> c:\..\PBEWS_Client_Test\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs<b> &nbsp;&nbsp; Riga: </b> 586
        <br><br>

        <b>Traccia dello stack:</b> <br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>

[FaultException: Errore durante la verifica della sicurezza del messaggio.]
```

System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14799942
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +622
   PBEWS_Client_Test.ServiceReference1.PBEWS.RecuperaPolizza(Int32 idPolizza, Boolean modalita) +0
   PBEWS_Client_Test.ServiceReference1.PBEWSClient.RecuperaPolizza(Int32 idPolizza, Boolean modalita) in c:...\PBEWS_Client_Test\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:586
   PBEWS_Client_Test.PBEWS_TestForm.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:...\PBEWS_Client_Test\PBEWS_TestForm.aspx.cs:103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804

```
              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
```

**It says "An error occurred when verifying security for the message" and refers to Reference.cs, that is the file that has been created by Visual Studio tool when setting up the service reference. Lines from 577 to 590 contains the following code:**

```
public PBEWS_Client_Test.ServiceReference1.MRAnaAnagraficaBaseList RicercaAnagrafiche(System.Collections.Generic.List<Rgi.PassBroker.WCF.Contracts.CriterioRicercaWS> criteri) {
        return base.Channel.RicercaAnagrafiche(criteri);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<PBEWS_Client_Test.ServiceReference1.MRAnaAnagraficaBaseList> RicercaAnagraficheAsync(System.Collections.Generic.List<Rgi.PassBroker.WCF.Contracts.CriterioRicercaWS> criteri) {
        return base.Channel.RicercaAnagraficheAsync(criteri);
    }

    public Rgi.PassBroker.WCF.Contracts.PolPolizza RecuperaPolizza(int idPolizza, bool modalita) {
        return base.Channel.RecuperaPolizza(idPolizza, modalita);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Rgi.PassBroker.WCF.Contracts.PolPolizza> RecuperaPolizzaAsync(int idPolizza, bool modalita) {
        return base.Channel.RecuperaPolizzaAsync(idPolizza, modalita);
    }
```